# Nested Dynamic Query with SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE for binding the Parameters

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm having two Azure Databases Lets say DB1(primary) and DB2(secondary).
I've Created two External Data sources for both the DB1 so that they can talk to each other

External Data Source for *DB1* is **External_DB2**
External Data Source for *DB2* is **External_DB1**

I'm having a Sp in my *DB2*.Lets say the sp is **sp_DB2(@param1)**
Like that another sp in my *DB1*.Say  **sp_DB1(@param1,@outparam)**
(Ps:@outparam is a output parameter)

*My sp_DB2 is the Main Sp* (which calls all other Sp i.e, sp_DB1).

Inside my sp_DB2 i have the code like

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE
N'External_DB1',
N' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(max),@outparam nvarchar(max)
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N''EXEC DBO.[sp_DB1]@param1,@outparam OUTPUT'',
N''@param1 nvarchar(max),@outparam nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'',
@param1 ,@outparam OUTPUT
SELECT @param1 AS Paramvalue,@outparam AS outputvalue'
```

Since sp_Execute_remote doesn't support the output param.I done like the above.But here the thing i want to bind the @param1 value from the Original Sp (**sp_DB2**).

If i tried like this it works,

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE
    N'External_DB1',
    N' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(max)=''Testing'',@outparam nvarchar(max)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N''EXEC DBO.[sp_DB1]@param1,@outparam OUTPUT'',
    N''@param1 nvarchar(max),@outparam nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'',
    @param1 ,@outparam OUTPUT
    SELECT @param1 AS Paramvalue,@outparam AS outputvalue'
```

Where i hardcoded the Value of @Param1 as **Testing** in the Code.

But actually the value of @Param1 should come from the original Sp which is **sp_DB2**

When i call the Original Sp like **sp_DB2(Testing)** It should bind with the @Param1 for the other Sp which is **sp_DB1**

By doing this we can reduce the Hardcoded value of Testing inside the Sp

Pls somebody help me to solve this

Thanks in Advance ! 
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE in Azure works very similar to native sp_executesql. So you should be able to bind the params & values. But I believe there is a limitation that you can't get a output param value from it. Try this and see if it works for your case. Thanks.

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE
    N'External_DB1',
    N' DECLARE @param1 nvarchar(max)= @param1_from_sp_DB2, @outparam nvarchar(max)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N''EXEC DBO.[sp_DB1]@param1,@outparam OUTPUT'',
    N''@param1 nvarchar(max),@outparam nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'',
    @param1 ,@outparam OUTPUT
    SELECT @param1 AS Paramvalue,@outparam AS outputvalue', 
    N'@param1_from_sp_DB2 nvarchar(max)', 
    @param1 --Since this is the input param name from sp_DB2
```

Answer (score -2):

please try this:

```
 Create PROCEDURE prLocalProcCallingRemoteProcWithOutput
        @LocalParam varchar(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE
    N'External_DB1',
    N' DECLARE  @outparam nvarchar(max)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N''EXEC DBO.[sp_DB1] @param1,@outparam OUTPUT'',
    N''@param1 nvarchar(max),@outparam nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'',
    @param1 ,@outparam OUTPUT
    SELECT @param1 AS Paramvalue,@outparam AS outputvalue',
     @params = N'@param1 nvarchar(100)',
    @param1 = @LocalParam


    END
    GO
```